# C# error propagating up the stack when it should not

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I'm encountering an issue where a service is exiting on errors that should never propagate up.

I built a microservice manager (.NET as the local environment doesnt support .NET Core and some of its native microservice abilities)

Built in VS2019 targeting .NET 4.5.2 (I know, but this is the world we live in)

For the microservice manager, it is built and installed as a windows service. Entry looks like this (#if/#else was for testing locally, it is working as intended when registered as a windows service)

Program.cs (Entry point)

```
   ` static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Scheduler myScheduler = new Scheduler();
            myScheduler.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#else
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {
                new Scheduler()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
        }
    }`
```

Scheduler.cs
//(confidential code hidden)

```
`private static readonly Configuration config = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(
            File.ReadAllText(configFilePath)
        );



        public Scheduler()
        {
            //InitializeComponent(); //windows service, doesnt need UI components initialized
        }
        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null); //triggers when developing locally
        }

        protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                logger.Log($@"Service manager starting...");
                
                logger.Log($@"Finding external services... {config.services.Count} services found.");
                
                foreach (var service in config.services)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (service.disabled)
                        {
                            logger.Log(
                                $@"Skipping {service.name}: disabled=true in Data Transport Service's appSettings.json file");
                            continue;
                        }
                        
                        logger.Queue($@"Starting: {service.name}...");
                        string serviceLocation = service.useRelativePath
                            ? Path.Combine(assemblyLocation, service.path)
                            : service.path;
                        var svc = Assembly.LoadFrom(serviceLocation);

                        var assemblyType = svc.GetType($@"{svc.GetName().Name}.Program");
                        var methodInfo = assemblyType.GetMethod("Main");
                        var instanceObject = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType, new object[0]);

                        methodInfo.Invoke(instanceObject, new object[0]);
                        logger.Queue(" Running").Send("");
                    }
                    catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
                    {
                        logger.Queue(" Failed").Send("");
                        logger.Log("an error occurred", LOG.LEVEL.CRITICAL, ex);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.Queue(" Failed").Send("");
                        logger.Log("an error occurred", LOG.LEVEL.CRITICAL, ex);
                    }
                    
                }
                logger.Log("Finished loading services.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Log($@"Critical error encountered", LOG.LEVEL.CRITICAL, ex);

            }
        }
```

Microservice:

```
public [Confidential]()
        {
            if (currentProfile == null)
            {
                var errMsg =
                    $@"Service not loaded, Profile not found, check appSettings.currentProfile: '{config.currentProfile}'";
                logger.Log(errMsg,severity: LOG.LEVEL.CRITICAL);
                throw new SettingsPropertyNotFoundException(errMsg);
            }
            if (currentProfile.disabled)
            {
                var errMsg = $@"Service not loaded: {config.serviceName}, Service's appSettings.currentProfile.disabled=true";
                logger.Log(errMsg,LOG.LEVEL.WARN);
                throw new ArgumentException(errMsg);
            }
            logger.Log($@"Loading: '{config.serviceName}' with following configuration:{Environment.NewLine}{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentProfile,Formatting.Indented)}");

            logger.Queue($@"Encrypting config file passwords...");
            bool updateConfig = false;
            foreach (var kafkaSource in config.dataTargets)
            {
                if (!kafkaSource.password.IsEncrypted())
                {
                    updateConfig = true;
                    logger.Queue($@"%tabEncrypting: {kafkaSource.name}");
                    kafkaSource.password = kafkaSource.password.Encrypt();
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Queue($@"%tabAlready encrypted: {kafkaSource.name}");
                }
            }
            logger.Send(Environment.NewLine);
            if (updateConfig)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(
                    configFilePath,
                    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config));
            }
            
            var _source = config.dataSources.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.name==currentProfile.dataSource);
            var _target = config.dataTargets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == currentProfile.dataTarget);

            source = new Connectors.Sql(logger, 
                _source?.name, 
                _source?.connectionString, 
                _source.pollingInterval,
                _source.maxRowsPerSelect, 
                _source.maxRowsPerUpdate);
            

            target = new Connectors.KafkaProducer(logger)
            {
                bootstrapServers = _target?.bootstrapServers,
                name = _target?.name,
                password = _target?.password.Decrypt(),
                sslCaLocation = Path.Combine(assemblyLocation,_target?.sslCaLocation),
                topic = _target?.topic,
                username = _target?.username
            };
            
            Start();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            try
            {
                logger.Log($@"SQL polling interval: {source.pollingInterval} seconds");


                timer.Interval = source.pollingInterval * 1000;
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
                timer.Start();
                if (currentProfile.executeOnStartup)
                    Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.AppendLine($@"Critical error encountered loading external service: {config.serviceName}.");
                if (!timer.Enabled)
                    sb.AppendLine($@"service unloaded - Schedule not started!");
                else
                    sb.AppendLine($@"service appears to be loaded and running on schedule.");

                logger.Log(sb.ToString(), LOG.LEVEL.CRITICAL, ex);
            }
        }
        public void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Log($@"Critical error during scheduled run on service: {config.serviceName}.", LOG.LEVEL.CRITICAL, ex);
            }
        }

        public async void Run()
        {
            //Get new alarm events from SQL source
            logger.Queue("Looking for new alarms...");
            var rows = await GetNewEvents();`
```

The exception occurred during the GetNewEvents method, which attempted to open a SqlConnection to a SQL server that was unavailable due to network issues, that method intentionally throws an exception, which should throw up to OnTimer, where it gets caught, logged, and the timer keeps running.  During development/testing, I used invalid credentials, bad connection string, etc and simulated this type of error and it worked as expected, logged the error, kept running. For some reason recently, that error is not caught in OnTimer, it propagates up, where it should be caught by Start (but isn't), after that it should be caught by the parent service manager which is entirely wrapped in a try/catch with no throw's, and above that (because their could be multiple microservices managed by that service) the entry point to the service manager is wrapped in try/catch with no throws, all for isolation from microservice errors.  For some reason though, now, the error from a VERY downstream application is propagating all the way up.

Typically, this code runs 24/7 no issues, the microservice it is loading from the config file launches and runs fine.  The entry into that specific microservice starts with a try {...} catch (Exception ex) {...} block.

The concept is to have a microservice manager than can launch a number of microservices without having to install all of them as windows services, and have some level of configuration driven by a config file that dictates how the main service runs.

The microservice represented here opens a SQL connection, reads data, performs business logic, publishes results to Kafka, it does this on a polling interval dictated by the config file contained in the microservice.  As stated above, its ran for months without issue.

Recently, I noticed the main microservice manager service was not running on the windows server, I investigated the Server Application Logs and found a "Runtime Error" that essentially stated the microservice, while attempting to connect to sql, failed (network issue) and caused the entire microservice manager to exit.  To my understanding, they way I'm launching the microservice should isolate it from the main service manager app.  Additionally, the main service manager app is wrapped in a very generic try catch block.  The entry point to the micro service itself is wrapped in a try catch, and almost every component in the microservice is wrapped in try / catch per business need.  The scenario that faulted (cant connect to sql) intentionally throws an error for logging purposes, but should be caught by the immediate parent try/catch, which does not propagate or re-throw, only logs the error to a txt file and the windows server app log.

How is it that this exception is bubbling up through isolation points and causing the main service to fault and exit?  I tested this extensively during development and prior to release, this exact scenario being unable to connect to sql, and it generated the correct log entry, and tried again on the next polling cycle as expected.

I haven't tried any other approaches as yet, as I feel they would be band-aid fixes as best as I dont understand why the original design is suddenly failing.  The server hasn't changed, no patching/security updates/etc.

From the server Application Log:
Application: DataTransportService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Exception
at Connectors.SqlHelper.DbHelper+d__13`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at IntelligentAlarms.IntelligentAlarm+d__14.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at IntelligentAlarms.IntelligentAlarm+d__12.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_1(System.Object)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: The only reference to GetNewEvents is at the very bottom of your code you have posted, which is the method call itself.  I don't see how this is answerable without seeing the code for GetNewEvents.  If you don't want an exception to go up the stack, you have to catch it.  Are you doing that?  Are you catching the right *type* of exception?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't feel it was relevant.  that method generated an exception (I just added the stacktrace that I forgot to include upon posting).  The error it generated was due to inability to open a SQL connection, but if you look at all the code prior to GetNewEvents you'll see everything is wrapped in very generic try/catch(Exception) blocks which should prevent any propagation (to my understanding). Regardless of the code inside GetNewEvents, it should be handled, right? The code never tries to catch specific exception types, but the base System.Exception

Comment: @RobertHarvey to clarify "not relevant" the purpose of the main service manager is to launch various microservices, if they error it should not propagate up or be able to affect other microservices, if a microservice fails that's its fault, the service manager shouldn't be adversely affected, or at least that's the design intention. The target of the post isn't to troubleshoot the microservice that faulted, but to discern how it was able to propagate far enough to fault the service manager

Comment: You don't have a try/catch block around `GetNewEvents()`.

Comment: And that's not the only problem.  There's a transition between `async` and synchronous in your code.  I don't know that wrapping the synchronous part can reasonably be expected to reliably catch an exception that occurs in an `async` block downstream.  Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch); it explains how to properly catch exceptions that arise from `async` methods.

Comment: You are not awaiting Run in   `try
            {
                Run();
            }`
so `try` is successfully exited before Run encounters any problem.

Comment: Ah, that's probably the problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the link, that makes a lot of sense, I've used async/await for years but never quite like this (microservice manager that doesnt care about responses), I assumed my traditional try/catch approach would catch, but considering all the scenarios like not awaiting, or having an async void / etc, ultimately it returns a task not an error, even if the task has an error, it still a task. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @Serg exactly, and a few other design decisions I'm going to change.  Ultimate goal is complete isolation between the main service and child services as the main service (and its owners) dont want/need to be responsible for microservices developed by other parties.  The concept was just a generic microservice launcher, technically not a manager, to reduce the number of services installed and provide some core features like logging/best practices for opening/closing/disposing of database connectors/etc, so microservices only require business logic and not expertise on resource management

Comment: `complete isolation ... provide some core features` Those two goals are somewhat at odds with each other. For truly "complete isolation", you would need to use separate processes. But providing core features is easier to do in the same process.

Comment: @StephenCleary you are correct, I didn't explain well (I was running on 30+ hrs or so without sleep), This is a service manager responsible for just starting unmanaged microservices, should be 100% isolated from them.  Separate class libraries were developed to facilitate things like dealing with sql, kafka, logging, etc and are referenced at need by the microservices.  The package is distributed as a service manager with helper services, 3rd parties can quickly develop microservices and optionally use the helper services, and use the service manager to launch them

Comment: @P.Thatcher: It does kind of sound like you're rewriting SCM, but assuming that's what you want to do... then for full proper isolation I'd recommend separate processes. You can still provide common services as NuGet packages, which may or may not communicate with the parent process.

Comment: I believe this specific error is caused by `async void Run` - `async void` methods have special exception handling semantics. Any exceptions propagated from an `async void` method are raised on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of that method. In the case of a Console/Win32 service, this is the thread pool `SynchronizationContext`, which will raise the exception directly on a thread pool thread, which crashes the process. You can *try* to work around it by handling `AppDomain.UnhandledException`, but it's a bandaid. Proper isolation requires a separate process.